# what type of data do *args accept? The function works with direct input, but errors if tuples/lists variables are entered (below: "numbers")

Tags: python, list, function, tuples, args

```py
def add_unlimited(*args):
    sum = 0
    for n in args:
        sum += n
    print(sum)
    
    
numbers = [23, 45, 23, 56]  
add_unlimited(23, 45, 23, 56)
```

Comment: `args` accepts any valid type. You can even mix tuples of lists of integers, and plain strings together. This is equivalent to type annotating it like `*args: Any` - signifying that each argument can be any type.

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error and the relevant code causing it as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: You can use `add_unlimited(*numbers)` to spread the list elements into separate arguments.

Comment: Do you see the pattern? You use `*args` to combine all the arguments into a list, and `*numbers` to spread the list into arguments.

Comment: @MichaelButscher
add_unlimited(numbers) in the above would result in the following error:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'list'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`def add_unlimited(*args)` accepts *an arbitrary amount* of arguments. Inside the function, the arguments are accessible in the form of a `list`, which is named `args`.

Note that `add_unlimited([23, 45, 23, 56])` is calling the function with *one* argument. That argument happens to be a list, `[23, 45, 23, 56]`. Inside the function, this will result in `args = [[23, 45, 23, 56]]`. The rest of your code inside the function doesn't work if each argument is not an integer, which is why you get an error.

You can pass a single list as several arguments by using the unpacking operator `*`:
`add_unlimited(*[23, 45, 23, 56])` is equivalent to `add_unlimited(23, 45, 23, 56)`

Comment: thank you. the unpacking operator did the trick: add_unlimited(*numbers)

Answer (score 1):

Please note that `*args` does not have any type restriction, unlike other static languages like Go. You can even mix tuples of lists of integers, and plain strings together. This is equivalent to type annotating it like `*args: Any` - signifying that each argument can be any type.

However, in this case, it looks like your function depends on each argument being a number. So I would type annotate it like `*args: Number`, to hint to the caller that each argument passed in should be a valid number.

Usage can be as below:

```py
from numbers import Number


def add_unlimited(*args: Number):
    sum = 0
    for n in args:
        sum += n
    print(sum)


numbers = [23, 45, 23, 56]
add_unlimited(*numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sum=0
for n in args:
    sum = 0 + [23, 45, 23, 56]
```

you can't add a list and zero.

you probably wanted something like

```
for x in args:
    for n in x:
        sum += n
```